# A complexe Procedure with SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have to create a procedure who return a result of a select query (I know with a simple view that's better, but this is an exercise so... i have to ^^" )

I made this procedure, but that's not perfect :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NbMoyenSession
IS
t1.nbSession t1.nbSession%TYPE;
t2.nbSessionCount t2.nbSession%TYPE;
BEGIN
--DECLARE nbSession Int;
SELECT t1.numsession, count(t2.numsession) INTO nbSession, nbSessionCount FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 WHERE t1.numsession = t2.numsession Group By t1.numsession;
dbms_output.put_line('test: ' ||t1.nbSession);
END;

EXECUTE PROCEDURE NbMoyenSession ();
```

I'm really lost in this exercise, somebody can help me ?

Comment: Look up pipelined functions in the Oracle manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're having trouble because you're selecting multiple rows into two scalar variables. Your quickest way to finish this would be to use a `SYS_REFCURSOR`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NbMoyenSession(NbSession OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN NbSession FOR
    SELECT t1.numsession, count(t2.numsession)
       FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
       WHERE t1.numsession = t2.numsession
       GROUP BY t1.numsession;
END;
```

To test it in SQL*Plus, just do the following:

```
SQL> VARIABLE testCur REFCURSOR
SQL> EXEC NbMoyenSession :testCur
SQL> PRINT testCur
```

You need the colon (`:`) before `testCur` in the second line above, but not in the first or third.

Comment: Thanks ! This is exactly what i wanted :) i understand better.